# 2-D convolution as a matrix-matrix multiplication

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, matrix-multiplication, convolution

I know that, in the 1D case, the convolution between two vectors, `a` and `b`, can be computed as `conv(a, b)`, but also as the product between the `T_a` and `b`, where `T_a` is the corresponding Toeplitz matrix for `a`.

Is it possible to extend this idea to 2D?

Given `a = [5 1 3; 1 1 2; 2 1 3]` and `b=[4 3; 1 2]`, is it possible to convert `a` in a Toeplitz matrix and compute the matrix-matrix product between `T_a` and `b` as in the 1-D case?

Comment: See [How can the convolution operation be implemented as a matrix-vector multiplication?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/11172/2444).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `deep-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/deep-learning/info).

Answer (score 69):

Yes, it is possible and you should also use a doubly block circulant matrix (which is a special case of [Toeplitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix) matrix). I will give you an example with a small size of kernel and the input, but it is possible to construct Toeplitz matrix for any kernel. So you have a 2d input `x` and 2d kernel `k` and you want to calculate the convolution `x * k`. Also let's assume that `k` is already flipped. Let's also assume that `x` is of size `n×n` and `k` is `m×m`.

So you unroll `k` into a sparse matrix of size `(n-m+1)^2 × n^2`, and unroll `x` into a long vector `n^2 × 1`. You compute a multiplication of this sparse matrix with a vector and convert the resulting vector (which will have a size `(n-m+1)^2 × 1`) into a `n-m+1` square matrix.

I am pretty sure this is hard to understand just from reading. So here is an example for 2×2 kernel and 3×3 input.

[image] * [image]

Here is a constructed matrix with a vector:

[image]

which is equal to [image].

And this is the same result you would have got by doing a sliding window of `k` over `x`.

Comment: There would have to be some sort of reshaping at the end correct? That last vector is 4 x 1 but the result of the convolution would be 2 x 2

Comment: @jvans yes, in the end you should reshape your vector. It is written here: **convert the resulting vector (which will have a size (n-m+1)^2 X 1) into a n-m+1 square matrix**

Comment: In your example this is not a Toeplitz matrix. So you answer is only partially correct, is it ?

Comment: What you mean by `Also let's assume that k is already flipped`? Is it because we want to perform correlation instead of convolution? What is `flipped` in terms of numpy operations?

Comment: @mrgloom Yes, the operation above is a correlation which is why he flips the filter vertically (upside down) first so it then becomes equivalent to a convolution. The numpy is `flip(m, 0)`, which is is equivalent to `flipud(m)`.

Comment: Just a short question: if I’ve multiple e.g. 2 channels, the rhs of the GEMM becomes a matrix with two columns, right?

Comment: So what are the details? How should `k` be unrolled into a sparse matrix?

Comment: @SalvadorDali Shouldnt the dimensions of the resulting convolutions be (m + n - 1) x (m+n-1) rather than (n-m+1) x (n-m+1)?

Comment: Am I correct that I should be able to replicate the effect of zero padding the input image by adding proper rows to the convolution matrix? Any insight into efficiently generating those rows?

Answer (score 44):

### 1- Define Input and Filter

Let **I** be the input signal and **F** be the filter or kernel.

[image: 2d input signal and filter]

### 2- Calculate the final output size

If the I is **m1 x n1** and F is m2 x n2 the size of the output will be:

[image]

### 3- Zero-pad the filter matrix

Zero pad the filter to make it the same size as the output.

[image]

### 4- Create Toeplitz matrix for each row of the zero-padded filter

[image]

### 5- Create a doubly blocked Toeplitz matrix

Now all these small Toeplitz matrices should be arranged in a big doubly blocked Toeplitz matrix.
[image]

[image]

### 6- Convert the input matrix to a column vector

[image]

### 7- Multiply doubly blocked toeplitz matrix with vectorized input signal

This multiplication gives the convolution result.

### 8- Last step: reshape the result to a matrix form

[image]

For more details and python code take a look at my github repository:

[Step by step explanation of 2D convolution implemented as matrix multiplication using toeplitz matrices in python](https://github.com/alisaaalehi/convolution_as_multiplication)

Comment: I think there is an error. The first element of the result should be 10*0 + 20*0 + 30*0 +40*1 = 40. The element in position 2,2 should be 1*10 + 2*20 + 4*30 + 5*40 = 370. I think your result is correct for a matrix F equal to [40 30; 20 10] that is exactly F flipping both rows and columns. There is therefore an error in the procedure

Comment: It is doing convolution (mathematical convolution, not cross-correlation), so if you are doing it by hand, you need to flip the filter both vertically and horizontally.
You can find more information on my GitHub repo.

Comment: This is a great explanation of 2D convolution as a matrix operation. Is there a way to represent "mode='same'" also? (i.e. keeping the output shape the same as the image)?

Comment: @ajl123 I think it should be. I'll work on it if I get time. Please feel free to dig into the code and math and send me a pull request on Github if you get the answer.

Comment: shouldn't the dimension of the resulting matrix decrease?

Comment: Is there a way to rewrite the operations to make both arguments symmetric in terms of operations? Currently you convert the filter to a doubly blocked Toeplitz matrix and the image to a vector. Is there a way to make this more symmetric (since convolution is commutative after all), so both argument would undergo the exact same operations?

Answer (score 3):

If you unravel k to a m^2 vector and unroll X, you would then get:

- a `m**2` vector`k`
- a `((n-m)**2, m**2)` matrix for `unrolled_X`

where `unrolled_X` could be obtained by the following Python code:

```
from numpy import zeros


def unroll_matrix(X, m):
  flat_X = X.flatten()
  n = X.shape[0]
  unrolled_X = zeros(((n - m) ** 2, m**2))
  skipped = 0
  for i in range(n ** 2):
      if (i % n) < n - m and ((i / n) % n) < n - m:
          for j in range(m):
              for l in range(m):
                  unrolled_X[i - skipped, j * m + l] = flat_X[i + j * n + l]
      else:
          skipped += 1
  return unrolled_X
```

Unrolling X and not k allows a more compact representation (smaller matrices) than the other way around for each X - but you need to unroll each X. You could prefer unrolling k depending on what you want to do.

Here, the `unrolled_X` is not sparse, whereas `unrolled_k` would be sparse, but of size `((n-m+1)^2,n^2)` as @Salvador Dali mentioned.

Unrolling `k` could be done like this:

```
from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix
from numpy import zeros
import scipy 


def unroll_kernel(kernel, n, sparse=True):

    m = kernel.shape[0]
    if sparse:
         unrolled_K = lil_matrix(((n - m)**2, n**2))
    else:
         unrolled_K = zeros(((n - m)**2, n**2))

    skipped = 0
    for i in range(n ** 2):
         if (i % n) < n - m and((i / n) % n) < n - m:
             for j in range(m):
                 for l in range(m):
                    unrolled_K[i - skipped, i + j * n + l] = kernel[j, l]
         else:
             skipped += 1
    return unrolled_K
```

Answer (score 1):

The code shown above doesn't produce the unrolled matrix of the right dimensions. The dimension should be (n-k+1)*(m-k+1), (k)(k). k: filter dimension, n: num rows in input matrix, m: num columns.

```
def unfold_matrix(X, k):
    n, m = X.shape[0:2]
    xx = zeros(((n - k + 1) * (m - k + 1), k**2))
    row_num = 0
    def make_row(x):
        return x.flatten()

    for i in range(n- k+ 1):
        for j in range(m - k + 1):
            #collect block of m*m elements and convert to row
            xx[row_num,:] = make_row(X[i:i+k, j:j+k])
            row_num = row_num + 1

    return xx
```

For more details, see my blog post:

http://www.telesens.co/2018/04/09/initializing-weights-for-the-convolutional-and-fully-connected-layers/