# How can I generate a Toeplitz matrix in the correct form for performing discrete convolution?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, convolution, toeplitz

Discrete convolution can be performed via the Toeplitz matrix, as shown  below [(Wiki article)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix#Discrete_convolution):

[image]

Note that this is not the exact same form as as the general Toeplitz matrix, but it has experienced various shifts and zero-paddings.

Is there a way to achieve this in numpy purely based on `roll`, `hstack` etc., i.e. without using any `for` loops? I have tried all sorts of shifts but I can't really get it in to the form shown above.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`scipy.linalg.toeplitz`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.toeplitz.html):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg

h = np.arange(1, 6)

padding = np.zeros(h.shape[0] - 1, h.dtype)
first_col = np.r_[h, padding]
first_row = np.r_[h[0], padding]

H = linalg.toeplitz(first_col, first_row)

print(repr(H))
# array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
#        [3, 2, 1, 0, 0],
#        [4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
#        [5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
#        [0, 5, 4, 3, 2],
#        [0, 0, 5, 4, 3],
#        [0, 0, 0, 5, 4],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 5]])
```

Comment: would this work for 2x2 numpy arrays as input signals ?

Comment: No, `scipy.linalg.toeplitz` treats all of its inputs as 1D arrays. I'm not sure what a 2x2 input array would mean in this context, anyway.

Comment: convolution between an image and a an image kernel for example.

Comment: which apparently can be achieved in matlab through this method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798888/2-d-convolution-as-a-matrix-matrix-multiplication

Comment: As in that MATLAB question, if your kernel is x-y separable then you could express it as two 1D vectors of weights, then construct two separate Toeplitz matrices as above and compute two separate dot products along different axes of your image array.