# Convert Conv2d to Linear

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I have a PyTorch [`Conv2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html) layer:

```
Conv2d(96, 1000, kernel_size=torch.Size([10, 10]), stride=(1, 1))
```

I know that a `Conv2d` layer is a special case of a [`Linear`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Linear.html) layer. How can I convert a `Conv2d` layer to `Linear` layer in PyTorch?

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't call a convolutional layer a "special case of a linear layer". But to your question: Do you mean how to flatten a conv layer output to a linear layer? Since you need matrices for conv. layers and for vectors linear layers, you have to take the matrix an flatten it, for example a matrix of shape (m, n) would become a vector (m*n, 1). Here is how to do that in Pytorch:

```py
x = nn.Conv2d(96, 1000, kernel_size=torch.Size([10, 10]), stride=(1, 1))
x = x.view(-1, x.size()[1] * x.size()[2] * x.size()[3])
```

x can now be passed into a flatten layer. Hope that helped!

Comment: Actually I want to replace the conv2d layer with Linear, and still have the same effect

Comment: what do you mean with "replace" ?

Comment: Convolution can indeed be expressed as a matrix multiplication, see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798888/2-d-convolution-as-a-matrix-matrix-multiplication). From what I can see, the answers also provide some ways of how to do this in code.